# How can i design a detailFragment like a webview?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm a beginner level Kotlin developer student.

I'm trying to make an app like this one ;

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ca.vsong.scpreader&hl=en&gl=US

I'm have  a list in listFragment and I have a detailFragment.I wanted to show each scps's details in detailFragment.There are over 2000 scps and each of them have different details.

For example this one;

https://scp-wiki.wikidot.com/scp-006

This one has 4 different paragraphs and one image so I should put 4 textView and one imageView and  my model file and json file must have 4 different info.

But my problem is each scps has different page design,let's look at this one;

https://scp-wiki.wikidot.com/scp-081

This one has  9 different paragraphs and no image so there must be 9 textView and no image but we have created detailPage with 4 textView and one imageView.

This is my question,how can i do this ? I know the app I shared is using webview but my goal is translating those scps into my language and show them so I created a json file and host it in Github.I don't know if it's best way,if you know better way please share with me

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that the easiest way is to use a `WebView`. A webview does not mean that it has to load the webpage you shared you can still store you data in app in a more mobile friendly way, or load content that was stored in a json and at runtime converted to HTML.

If you want to go with the screen by screen approach of combination of `TextView` and `ImageView` for each page you can do it so by creating a dynamic layout and in the json file also store the UI details ie. `{type: "TEXT", content: "Lorem"}` then when you see "TEXT" you will use a `TextView`. It won't be easy because there is no automated way to convert the data in json so you have to read and convert all pages to json one by one but it is feasible.

Regarding the dynamic UI coding part this can achieved in multiple ways.

- Create all the views and layout by code without use of xml files.
- Use multiple xml as construction blocks and depending on the json type do the dynamic UI construction. Page XML: a `ScrollView` and a `LinearLayout` this will be the main, an xml for the `TextView` and an xml for the `ImageView`. Then depending on the type you find in the json you use the `LayoutInflater` and `inflate` each layout and attach it to view.
- Use a `RecyclerView` with multiple layout types. You can find quite enough examples online for that ie. [Example 1](https://blog.mindorks.com/recyclerview-multiple-view-types-in-android), [Example 2](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/recyclerview-with-multiple-view-types/). I believe that this way will provide the smoothest scrolling experience.

Comment: I don't know how json converted to HTML and how can i use webview if there isnt any
views.Do you mean that we can create views in json file? I couldn't understand the first paragraph.

Second paragraph.{type: "TEXT", content: "Lorem"} then when you see "TEXT" you will use a TextView
Is there a guide about how to do this because I don't know how to do it.

The last part.Do you want me to create detailFragment in recyclerView like my list ?